# How to connect a Presto database to MySQL

Tags: mysql, presto

Is it possible to make joins between two tables from two different Presto catalogs? Assume I have a `product` table in MySQL and another table `sales_order` in hive; can I join them? If yes, then how can I specify the catalog for MySQL and what would my query look like?

Answer (score 4):

### **EDIT: Since [v0.76](http://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.76.html) Presto adds a MySQL connector and a PostgreSQL connector.**

For now, prestodb is not capable to connect to a relational database like mysql. More info in [presto FAQ](http://prestodb.io/faq.html):

> Does Presto connect to MySQL / PostgreSQL / Oracle?
>
> Not yet. We have a basic JDBC connector in development. Note that this is for connecting to  an external JDBC database. Presto already includes a JDBC driver that allows Java applications to connect to Presto.