# Can PrestoDB connect to the relational databases like Oracle?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, presto

If presto is able to connect Oracle or Mysql please tell me how to connect.

hadoop 2.1.1
hive 0.12.0
presto 0.65
java jdk 7
oracle 10g

Comment: Related: [How to connect prestodb with mysql or any other rdbms.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166694/how-to-connect-prestodb-with-mysql-or-any-other-rdbms/25483580#25483580)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not yet have a connector available for Oracle, but we do have connectors for MySQL and PostgreSQL:

- http://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/mysql.html
- http://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/postgresql.html